# How to retrieve list of registered callback URLs?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

We're using Watson's asynchronous HTTP interface (https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/async.html#async) for Speech-to-Text tasks.

We've registered multiple callbacks URLs and now we're having troubles with managing them. Is there any simple way to retrieve list of all registered callbacks associated with given Watson service account? The only endpoints that I have found in the docs are for registering and unregistering callbacks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, **there is no mechanism** to list the existing callbacks.

I think it's a good idea so why don't you add it to Aha! https://ibm-watson.ideas.aha.io.
The Watson team is using that to gather ideas/feedback.

Answer (score 1):

i looked at the API docs here - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/#async_methods. Looks like your requirement is not supported at the moment. as said before you can add this as an idea to Watson ideas.